# Having problems with Bootstrap and aligning h3 and select options on same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a program, and using Bootstrap to aid me in the CSS.

I am having some issues with making the select dropdown and the h3 tag's appear on the same line.

Currently it looks like this:

[image: Imgur]

**Goal:**
I am trying to make it appear like this:

....Convert from: [drop down box here]

....Convert from: [drop down box here]

So that it all appears on the same line

HTML:

```
  <div class="row buttons">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <div class="col-md-8 text-center col-centered ">
        <h3>Select your which number type you would like to convert <span>from</span>:</h3>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" style="width: 100px;">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>

        <h3>Select your which number type you would like to convert <span>to</span>:</h3>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" style="width: 100px;">
          <option value="one">One</option>
          <option value="two">Two</option>
          <option value="three">Three</option>
          <option value="four">Four</option>
          <option value="five">Five</option>
        </select>

        <button type="button" class="binaryConversion selected">Convert from Binary</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @connexo thats why we play around with it, ask and learn, before we use it on live-webpages.  Your condescending attitude and comment poses no help whatsoever.

Comment: You should use a `<label>` tag, instead of a `<h3>`.

Comment: @jward01 - Don't worry about what others say, it's good that you came here to ask! The community should be here to help nourish the talents of the programmers and developers of the future (and most of us are)! There's no such thing as a stupid question and you included a screenshot and code snippit so I'd say you made an effort to explain your issue.

Comment: @AlvinPascoe Thank you!  you are awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<H3>` tag is set to `display:block` (Bootstrap also sets the `<select>` tag to `display:block` via its `.form-control` class).

Certain elements are set to `display:block` by default, this means they occupy a whole row of the screen (so no element will natively sit along side them).

You can change them to `display:inline-block` in order to get them to show up on the same line:

http://jsfiddle.net/61519vsz/

For more information regarding CSS `display` here is are a couple of useful links:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: I think the default display value for `<select>` is `inline-block;` already. Not block.

Comment: @ChrisYongchu - That's true however Bootstrap is overriding the `<select>` styles and making it `display:block`.

Comment: I see that. Probably a reason why they did it within a form. I wonder if it will have any affects on mobile. Why does he have `form-control` when his markup isn't using a form?

Comment: @ChrisYongchu -  I'm not sure...it most likely isn't the best structure for what he's trying to do but completely rewritting the snippit may be a little overwhelming (and more confusing). He now understands CSS display (or knows how to find out more) and that knowledge can be incrementally built upon as he gets more experience with front-end development.

Answer (score 1):

Heading Elements `<h1>, <h2>,...` are blocked elements. You need to change the `display` value to `inline-block`. Something like:

```
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a demo for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/c5gm2ufk/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "form-horizontal" class from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).  jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j1z3v2st/).

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <label class="control-label"> Hello
    <select class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
    </select>
</label>
</form>`
```